How to calculate this limit $I_{R,\sigma}$?
Suppose $I_{R,\sigma}=\oint_\limits{x^{2}+xy+y^{2}=R^{2} }^{}\frac{xdy-ydx}{\left (x^{2}+y^{2}\right )^\sigma}$ , I want to calculate $$\lim_{R \to+\infty} = I_{R,\sigma}$$
I've used two transforms , the first one is
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
  x=\frac{u-v}{\sqrt{2} }  \\  
  y=\frac{u+v}{\sqrt{2} } 
\end{matrix}\right.$$
$x^{2}+xy+y^{2}=R^{2}$ can tranform to $\left (\frac{u}{\sqrt{\frac{2}{3} }R }  \right )^{2}  +\left ( \frac{v}{\sqrt{2}R }  \right )^{2}=1$ , then I used
$$\left\{\begin{matrix} 
  u=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}R \text{cos }\theta  \\  
  v=\sqrt{2}R \text {sin }\theta  
\end{matrix}\right.$$
then $$I_{R,\sigma}=\frac{\sqrt{3} }{3}\cdot \frac{1}{R^{2 \sigma -2} }  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{\left ( \frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{3}\sin ^{2}\theta     \right )^{\sigma
}  }d \theta  $$
but when $\sigma = 1$ , I could not calculate $$\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{1}{ \frac{2}{3}+\frac{4}{3}\sin ^{2}\theta     }d \theta$$
did I calculate wrong ?
